# Setting the Turtlebot initial pose estimate

Tags: ros, pose, rviz, turtlebot

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Having successfully made a map I'm following the instructions for navigation here:

http://www.ros.org/wiki/turtlebot_navigation/Tutorials/Autonomously%20navigate%20in%20a%20known%20map

But when attempting to set the initial pose the robot isn't relocated on the map.  I can see that there is an attempt to set the pose, like this:

```
[ INFO] [1319821331.969617532]: Setting pose: -0.708 -0.116 1.488 [frame=/map]
```

but within rviz the robot remains fixed in place.  I'm using the latest electric source code checked out and compiled.  On the turtlebot itself I am getting the following warning, which might not be related:

```
[ WARN] [1319821429.390001799]: Map update loop missed its desired rate of 3.0000Hz... the loop actually took 0.5033 seconds
```

The only parameter which is different from what's described in the wiki is the map yaml file, and that appears to have loaded correctly within rviz.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/11727/setting-the-turtlebot-initial-pose-estimate/) by [JediHamster](https://answers.ros.org/users/146/jedihamster/) on ROS Answers with karma: 995 on 2011-10-28

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

This often means that subscribers on the robot (in this case `amcl`) can't contact off-board publishers (in this case `rviz`).  Check the [network troubleshooting guide](http://www.ros.org/wiki/ROS/NetworkSetup) to verify that you have bi-directional communication; you may need to, for example, set `ROS_IP` on your off-board machine.

---

Originally posted by [Brian Gerkey](https://answers.ros.org/users/8/brian-gerkey/) with karma: 2916 on 2011-10-28

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [JediHamster](https://answers.ros.org/users/146/jedihamster/) on 2011-10-29**:
I think I've fixed the problem.  It looks as if both the robot and the remote computer both need to have explicit names set up for them within /etc/hosts - you can't just rely upon using IP addresses.

**Comment by [JediHamster](https://answers.ros.org/users/146/jedihamster/) on 2011-10-28**:
From tests it appears that the network is set up ok.  One warning which I often seem to be getting when starting the amcl demo is:  [ WARN] [1319886789.489061969]: Waiting on transform from /base_link to /map to become available before running costmap, tf error: